# Tmux copy-pipe with mouse selection

Tags: macos, mouse, tmux, copy-paste, clipboard

I use `copy-pipe` on OS X to share the system clipboard with Tmux 1.8:

```
unbind -t vi-copy Enter
bind -t vi-copy Enter copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

This works when entering select mode and copying text (select text, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>), but not when selecting text with the mouse. Is it possible to set a command that should run after mouse selection, just like `copy-pipe` runs after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>? I.e. I need to run `reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy` when the selection is left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to customize the “mouse up” behavior that ends a selection that was started by the mouse. For the details, see [the `reset_mode` label](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/1b083aa0fd2d8ac000504488135bf58e35c3361e/tree/window-copy.c#l867) of [`window_copy_mouse()`](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/1b083aa0fd2d8ac000504488135bf58e35c3361e/tree/window-copy.c#l830) in [`window-copy.c`](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/1b083aa0fd2d8ac000504488135bf58e35c3361e/tree/window-copy.c) (links are to the source of *tmux* 1.8); specifically, there are no references to window, session, or server options in this bit of code.

There is a workaround, but it is probably a bit of an edge case:

- Activate your `copy-pipe` binding (e.g. press Enter) before releasing the mouse button.
  This will run your shell command, copy the selection into a buffer, and exit copy mode (i.e. the usual behavior for `copy-pipe`).

There is a small side effect though:

- The mouse event that your terminal will send when you finally release the button will cause *tmux* to re-enter copy mode. You will need to manually exit (e.g. Escape or C-c) this “extra” copy mode.
  This could probably be considered a bug (`input_mouse()` does not check that the mouse event is a “button up” event before starting a new copy mode); but, it is mostly harmless (other than the inconvenience of having to exit the second copy mode instance).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I consider this the perfect answer! Maybe I will file a feature request for this.

Comment: It's possible for mouse selection to work without any of these shenanigans. I use iTerm 2, OSX Mavericks, and tmux 1.8, and any text I select in tmux (real tmux selection, not a terminal selection) is copied to the system clipboard. Alas, it works on one of my machines and not another (same versions of everything), and I can't for the life of me figure out why...but it's possible. I'll post my config once I figure out how to get it working on both.

Comment: @Chris: Do you know if the bug that you have mentioned above is fixed in 1.9?

Comment: @Behrang: The behavior seems to be unchanged as of version 1.9a.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen does this limitation still apply to tmux 2.0?

Comment: @muffel: Yes, it appears to be the same. Mouse support is reworked in (not yet released) 2.1; it looks like there is no way to bind the drag release event, but the “re-enters copy mode” problem with my suggested workaround seems to be fixed.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen thanks for the information! For me the "re-enters copy mode problem" still applies in 2.0, is any further configuration required in order to get rid of it?

Comment: @muffel: Right, 2.0 does not appear to change that; it is **2.1** (still in development/unreleased) that will change that particular behavior.

Answer (score 8):

For tmux 2.2 and later use:

```
bind-key -t emacs-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```

Comment: Under Mac OS Sierra, `reattach-to-user-namespace` is once again required for `pbcopy` under tmux.  `bind-key -t emacs-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"`  https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard